# Написание RPG с помощью C# и XNA в 3D

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

Вопрос определенно нубский, но раз уж он так часто появляется в сети, хотелось бы собрать все во едино в одном месте.

Я предлагаю начать с того, что же необходимо изучить, чтобы написать это, попутно буду задавать вопросы интересующие меня на определенном этапе. Надеюсь, сенсеи помогут разобраться раз и навсегда в этом вопросе.
Пожалуй начну список я, жду дельных советов куда идти, что изучать и прочих советов.
Прошу не писать негативных ответов не несущих смысловой нагрузки.

1. C#
2. Создание концепт документа (все то, что будет описывать геймплей)

Допустим я знаю C# (на деле я знаком с C++ не на суперском уровне, но кое что знаю + читаю "CLR via C#" на русском).

Есть некая идея для РПГ, некая история, задумки и т.д.

Что теперь?
Я имею ввиду, даже зная все это я мало представляю как оно должно быть написано.
Более или менее я понимаю, что должны быть отделены движки, но ни как это сделать ни о том как именно оно должно взаимодействовать я представления не имею. Быть может тут имеет место какой то паттерн программирования? Если так подскажите название.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[XNA RPG – изучение XNA по ходу создания RPG, серия из 26 руководств](https://web.archive.org/web/20140407132821/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rucoding4fun/archive/2011/06/20/xna-rpg-learning-xna-while-building-a-rpg-a-26-part-tutorial-series.aspx)

Если вдруг на Unity захотите [Unity 3D - Создание РПГ и программирование на C#](https://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3489789)

Answer (score 3):

Если вы решили писать игры на C# под XNA, то XNA - это и есть игровой движок для создания игр 2D и 3D под Windows, мобильных телефонов с ОС Windows Phone и приставку XBox-360. Поэтому нужно изучать книги и видео-уроки по XNA, для начала могу порекомендовать прочесть книгу: С. Г. Горнаков - Разработка игр под Windows в XNA Game Studio Express, ее можно скачать по одной из ссылок:
http://forcoder.ru/multimedia/razrabotka-igr-pod-windows-v-xna-game-studio-express-824
http://progbook.ru/c-sharp-net/834-gornakov-razrabotka-igr-pod-windows-v-xna-game.html
а также посмотреть видео-уроки по XNA по ссылке:
http://www.techdays.ru/videos/XNA
там нужно будет зарегистрироваться, это сайт по обучению технологиям от Microsoft.
И если вы не знакомы с C# - почитать параллельно с изучением XNA книгу:
Герберт Шилдт, "Полный справочник по C#" - ее легко найти и скачать, искать нужно последний выпуск за 2011 год. Там описывается язык C# в хорошей доступной форме, с примерами по каждой теме. Вот так выглядит обложка книги:
http://www.razym.ru/94766-gerbert-shildt-c-40-polnoe-rukovodstvo.html
У Шилдта несколько книг - нужна последняя версия C#

Comment: Я Джеффри Рихтера читаю по C#, пока вроде понятно)
Касаемо XNA мне казалось это просто фреймворк, а не движок. В прочем я почитаю эту книгу, надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Дж. Рихтер - это всё-таки не по C#. В своей книге он углубляется именно в платформу .NET и её механизмы, используя язык C# всего лишь как средство для демонстрации примеров.
Поэтому, если начинать C# с нуля, прсилушайтесь к совету выше и найдите последнее издание Шилдта. Читается легко и быстро, написано в понятной форме (впрочем, как обычно у Шилдта).
Ну а "CLR via C#" стоит читать в том случае, если Вы решили досканально разобраться в устройстве .NET-а, его узких местах и способах повысить производительность.

Answer (score 0):

Бенджамин Ницчке
Профессиональное программирование игр с XNA для Windows и Xbox 360
http://netlib.narod.ru/library/book0052/index.htm